# How can i download a zipped file from the internet using pandas 0.17.1 and python 3.5

Tags: pandas, download, zip

What am i doing wrong? here is what i am trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd

url='http://data.octo.dc.gov/feeds/crime_incidents/archive/crime_incidents_2013_CSV.zip'

df = pd.read_csv(url, compression='gzip',
                 header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"',
                 engine = 'python')
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Abbas, thanks so much.  Indeed i ran it step by step and here is what i came up with.  Not the fastest indeed, but it works fine.
I ran it with pandas 0.18.1 on python 3.5.1 on Mac

> 

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib.request import urlopen   
import pandas as pd
import os

URL = \
    'http://data.octo.dc.gov/feeds/crime_incidents/archive/crime_incidents_2013_CSV.zip'

# open and save the zip file onto computer
url = urlopen(URL)
output = open('zipFile.zip', 'wb')    # note the flag:  "wb"        
output.write(url.read())
output.close()

# read the zip file as a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('zipFile.zip')   # pandas version 0.18.1 takes zip files       

# if keeping on disk the zip file is not wanted, then:
os.remove(zipName)   # remove the copy of the zipfile on disk
```

I hope this helps.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Cy Bu didn't quite work for me in Python 3.6 on Windows. I was getting an invalid argument error when trying to open the file. I modified it slightly:

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

r = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
b2 = [z for z in url.split('/') if '.zip' in z][0] #gets just the '.zip' part of the url

with open(b2, "wb") as target:
    target.write(urlopen(r).read()) #saves to file to disk

data = pd.read_csv(b2, compression='zip') #opens the saved zip file
os.remove(b2) #removes the zip file
```

Comment: This answer was the only working solution for me! Slightly updated it, since often if you're trying to access an API programmatically you will get a 403 (forbidden) error. Then you must specify a 'User-Agent' in your request to the API.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC here is a solution instead of directly passing zip file to `pandas`, first unzip it and then pass the `csv` file:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib import urlopen
import pandas as pd

url = urlopen("http://data.octo.dc.gov/feeds/crime_incidents/archive/crime_incidents_2013_CSV.zip")
zipfile = ZipFile(StringIO(url.read()))
f = open(zipfile.NameToInfo.keys()[0],'wb')
f.write(zipfile.open(zipfile.NameToInfo.keys()[0]).read())
f.close()

df = pd.read_csv(zipfile.NameToInfo.keys()[0])
```

And will produce a `DataFrame` like this:

[image]

Comment: this solution doesn't work as i don't seem to be able to use the
from urllib import url open...

The issue i am running into is that my code raises the error message: 
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1093, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: Were you able to download the zip file using  a browser?

Comment: Are you able to unzip it (using 7zip or similar applications) and load the csv file to `pandas`?

Comment: yes, i can download any zip file and unzip (on mac) without any problem all manually though.   Just like i can do on that file given in the example above.

Comment: OK, if so I don't have a Mac to evaluate this solution in it, ideally it shall work. If not then go step by step and evaluate what you are getting after every step. Like just write the content of url.read() to a file and evaluate it and then with every step.